# How should i index this?

Tags: index

i always had this question and i hope you can help me with this, how should i index created_at if i need to order results based on date.

Example:

COMMENTS TABLE:

- ID (UUID)
- ENTRY_ID (UUID)
- USER_ID (UUID)
- CONTENT
- FEATURED
- STATUS
- CREATED_AT

I have this indexes:

- PRIMARY: ID
- INDEX: ENTRY_ID
- INDEX: ENTRY_ID | CREATED_AT (to get latest entry comments)
- INDEX: USER_ID
- INDEX: USER_ID | CREATED_AT (to get latest user comments)
- INDEX: STATUS | CREATED_AT (to get comments marked as spam ordered by older first)
- INDEX: CREATED_AT (to get latest comments in entire db)

Is it right or i can skip some indexes?

Comment: Indexes should be added to resolve queries. We can't tell you what indexes to add if we don't know your data access patterns.

Comment: ... + 99% that separate indices by `ENTRY_ID` and by `USER_ID` are excess.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Indexing capabilities and usage depends highly on the database product.

Comment: In general you can remove all (non-unique) single column indexes where that column is a leading column in another index

Comment: Im currently using Postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You don't need single column indexes on fields that are also the first column in multi column indexes.

However you shouldn't specify the column order just based on that. For best performance, you want the column that has the highest cardinality (ie "uniqueness") first in the column order.

I think that you should just get rid of the CREATED_AT single column index and keep the other single column ones.

The 3 double column indexes should all  have the CREATED_AT field first ordered DESC for maximum efficiency.